# Mapear documentos MongoDB a POJOs java

Tags: java, array, json, mongodb

Estoy traspasando documentos de MongoDB a POJOs en java
pero cuando muestro un array(Vendidos) que estaba dentro del documento me aparece null

Formato JSON del documento:

[image: Formato]

Clase principal.java

```
        MongoCollection<Libros> collection = database.getCollection("Libros",Libros.class);
        Libros libro = collection.find(eq("isbn", 9509970667528L)).first();
        System.out.println("Libro encontrado:\t" + libro);
```

Clase Libros.java

```
public class Libros {

    @BsonProperty(value = "isbn")
    private long isbn;
    private String titulo;
    private String nombre_del_autor;
    private String editorial;
    private String tipo_genero;
    private String tipo_subgenero;
    private int stock;
    private int precio;
    private List<Vendidos> vendidos;

    //Setters y Getters

    public List<Vendidos> getVendidos(){
        return vendidos;
    }
    public Libros setVendido(List<Vendidos> vendidos){
        this.vendidos=vendidos;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Libro{");
        sb.append("isbn=").append(isbn);
        sb.append(", titulo=").append(titulo).append('\'');
        sb.append(", nombre del autor='").append(nombre_del_autor).append('\'');
        sb.append(", Edtorial='").append(editorial).append('\'');
        sb.append(", Tipo de genero='").append(tipo_genero).append('\'');
        sb.append(", Tipo de subgenero='").append(tipo_subgenero).append('\'');
        sb.append(", Stock='").append(stock).append('\'');
        sb.append(", Precio='").append(precio).append('\'');
        sb.append(", Vendidos='").append(vendidos).append('\'');


        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
}
```

Clase Vendidos.java

```
public class Vendidos {
    

    private int id_boleta;
    private int rut_cliente;
    private int fecha;
    private int hora;
    private String tipo_de_entrega;
    private int cantidad;
    private int precio_total;
    
   //Setters y Getters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Vendidos{");
        sb.append("id_boleta='").append(id_boleta).append('\'');
        sb.append("rut_cliente='").append(rut_cliente).append('\'');
        sb.append("fecha='").append(fecha).append('\'');
        sb.append("hora='").append(hora).append('\'');
        sb.append("tipo_de_entrega='").append(tipo_de_entrega).append('\'');
        sb.append("cantidad='").append(cantidad).append('\'');
        sb.append("precio_total='").append(precio_total).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Resultado

Libro encontrado:       Libro{isbn=9509970667528, titulo=Operación masacre', nombre del autor='Rodolfo Walsh', Edtorial='de bolsillo', Tipo de genero='Narrativo', Tipo de subgenero='Policiaca', Stock='49', Precio='10330', Vendidos='null'}

Vendidos aparece null

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes el `setVendidos` en la clase Libro? ¿Es lo que muestras? Si es lo que muestras probablemente sea esa la causa del error (te falta la s al final y el setter no es `void`). Generalmente los mapeadores se rigen por las convenciones de nombres. Si no tienes el setter nombrado de acuerdo a la propiedad (en este caso vendidos) y con la firma `void`, es muy probable la librería lo ignore y sea esa la causa del error. Asegúrate de tener un método `public void setVendidos`.

Comment: Oh muchas gracias, esa era la solucion, habia probado insertar un documento nuevo y igualmente me marcaba error en el value 'vendido' siendo que no lo encontraba, justo donde me marcaste faltaba la S, Gracias